# Skill enable when Alexa account linking "Invalid account linking credentials" integration with Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, alexa-skills-kit

I am following this documentation https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html in order to make an in app linking.

[image]

I get an error on the last step where I would like to do the skill enablement.

[image]

I am not sure what to put in redirectUri ?Is this a POST / GET ? Whos credentials are actually invalid ?

The redirect_uri parameter that was included in the authorization request to your OAuth 2.0 server to obtain the user's authorization code. This enables Amazon to retrieve access tokens from your token server. This URL must be opaque to Amazon.

Should be a link where Alexa can take tokens using the authorization code ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#2-get-an-access-token
I am stuck because I get 400 "Invalid account linking credentials".